# Zurb Foundation tooltips does not show up properly with Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, tooltip, zurb-foundation

I'm new to foundation, and I'm having issues using its tooltip with Chrome. It shows up all the way to the left, and it's too wide. This only happens with Chrome. With other browsers, it shows up right at the element that I hover on with the correct width.

The version of Chrome I am using is 37.0.2062.94, and I am using Zurb Foundation 5.2.2.

This is the code:

```
<i class="heart has-tip tip-bottom" data-tooltip data-selector="tooltip-htytz2g65" title></i>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. For future reference, you can add the code directly in your question instead of linking it to an image. More information on formatting can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).